# How to set multiple conditions to style in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table. I want to set different colors depending on the values of one of the columns.
I have managed to set two colors using NgClass. But how can I set three different conditions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<tr ng-class="{{project.total >= 0}} ? 'danger':'success'">

  <td>
    {{project.total}}

  </td>
</tr>
```

I want three conditions, if total is less than 35, color should be red, between 35 and 70 ; yellow and above 70 should be green.
How can i do this with angular.
I am very new to angular.

Comment: Why not set a variable on scope in controller and use it in template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an object as a value of `ng-class`.

From the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) :

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair
>   of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a
>   class name.

Your object will be something like that :

```
{
    'red': project.total < 35,
    'yellow': project.total >= 35 && project.total < 70,
    'green': project.total >= 70
}
```

Therefore, your html is :

```
<tr ng-class="{ 'red': project.total < 35, 'yellow': project.total >= 35 && project.total < 70, 'green': project.total >= 70 }">
```

**Edit**: See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o84asho/)

However, because of [angular's digest mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs) you should keep only simple conditions in your templates. The resulting class computation could be deported in the controller, and you would have only :

```
<tr ng-class="{{project.class}}">
```

Comment: 'yellow': project.total >= 35 and project.total < 70, and is giving errors

Comment: It is a typo, it should have been `project.total >= 35 && project.total < 70`. Was correct in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o84asho/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-class="{'red': project.total <35  , 'yellow':project.total >= 35 && project.total<70,'green': project.total >= 70 } ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, you should do work this complicated in a controller rather than the HTML, but if you insist, you could do this:

```
<tr ng-class="project.total < 35 ? 'danger': (project.total < 71 ? 'partial' : 'success')">
```

Comment: How would I do this in my controller, I am very new to angular I didnt know I could do the same in controller

Comment: Read the docs for [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).  Yours is the entirely standard case for a controller.